# Как в phpunit задать id сессии

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

```
    DB::table('team')->truncate();

    $this->get('public_api/teams')->seeJson(['data' => []]);
    $res = $this->get('public_api/teams?game_id=3')->decodeResponseJson();
    $this->assertEquals(1, count($res['data']));

    $res = $this->get('public_api/teams?game_id=3')->decodeResponseJson();
    $this->assertEquals(1, count($res['data']));
```

Например незалогиненый пользователь заходит на сайт и для него сразу создаётся команда. В таблицу команд записывается id сессии. если он заходит ещё раз то по id сессии выбирается команда. Смысл теста в том что бы проверить не создаётся ли команда каждый раз когда пользователь заходит. Но в тесте каждый раз новый id сессии, в отличии от браузера. Как сделать что бы в одном методе теста был один и тот же id сессии или может его можно задать в тесте?

Насколько я понимаю в тестах каждый тест это как будто пользователь открывает браузер, и соответственно создаётся новая сессия.

Comment: `$this->withSession()` - тебе не подходит ? только посмотри, что б были настройки сессии установлены в файле phpunit по умолчанию по-моему Array

Comment: и как её использовать?

Comment: Почитай в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing#sessions-and-authentication)

Comment: не работает такой способ